# Что за ошибка при установке Electron?

Tags: плагин, ember.js, electron, addons

**ubuntu 16.04 - node 6.9.2 - npm 3.10.9 - ember-cli: 2.10.0** - `ember install ember-electron`

```
    Installed packages for tooling via npm.
installing ember-electron
  identical config/environment.js
  identical electron.js
  identical tests/electron.js
  identical tests/package.json
Ember Electron requires configuration. Please consult the Readme to ensure that this addon works!
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-electron
  install packages electron, electron-packager, electron-rebuild, ember-inspector, devtron
Refusing to install electron as a dependency of itself
Error: Refusing to install electron as a dependency of itself
    at checkSelf (/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:53:14)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
    at LOOP (/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
    at chain (/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:16:5
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:35
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:52:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at asyncMap (/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:51:8)
```

Comment: дайте больше информации. как вы устанавливает? окружение?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman - ubuntu 16.04 - node 6.9.2 - npm 3.10.9 - ember-cli: 2.10.0 - `ember install ember-electron`

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос